# Prove that if a number N is divisible by x, then all the permutations of N's digits are also divisible by x

Tags: combinatorics

Given an ordered list of digits (6,5,4,3,2,1), in integer form would be 654321 which is divisible by 3. Any permutation, for example (5,6,4,3,2,1) or 564321 would also be divisible by 3. Prove (or disprove) this.

This is actually a problem I found in a programming exercise, so I was using a brute force method to check if all permutations are divisible by an x. It's not clear to me if the list of digits I chose happened to all be divisible, or if this is a rule that applies to any list of digits. It is also not clear if any number would be divisible, or only the example 3 I chose. I don't possess the mathematical skill to prove it with anything other than brute force.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It works only for $3$ and $9$ because a number is divisible by $3$ or $9$ if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$ or $9$.
So for any permutation of the digits the some remain the same.

Comment: The question in the title is very different from the question in the body. In particular, the question in the title has an easy counterexample, while the phrasing in the body has a simple proof.

Comment: $12$ is divisible by $2$ but $21$ not.

Comment: Hopefully the edit i made adds context.

Comment: @Essaidi it also works for $11$

Comment: No it doesn't work for $11$  : $121$ is divisible by $11$ but $112$ not.

Answer (score 1):

We're in base 10, and it's a well-known fact that an arbitrary number is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3.

However, this is not true for e.g. divisibility by 2: Essaldi's example from the comments is 12, which is even (so divisible by 2) vs 21, which is odd (so not divisible by 2).

But of course, for any number x and natural number n, you can cook up a number N with n digits and all of whose "permutations" are also divisible by x. Just use x as every digit, e.g. 22, 222, ...